# state is not updating in onchange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hi in my application we are using initialstate where the application sample data will be defined and using the context for state management, below is my sample initial state:

-

```
creditCard: {
           isSaved: false,
           lastFourDigits: "1235",
           loading: false,
           cardholder: "",
           cardnumber: "",
           cardmonth: "",
           cardyear: "",
           cardcvv: "",
         },
       etc:{}....
```

and in my component i am using usestate for setting the data as below :

```
 const { state,actionsCollection } = useContext(StateContext);
  const [cardholder, setcardholder] = useState("");
  const [cardnumber, setcardnumber] = useState("");
  const [cardmonth, setcardmonth] = useState("");
  const [cardyear, setcardyear] = useState("");
  const [cardcvv, setcardcvv] = useState("");
```

and in onchange i am setting state as below:

```
<TextField
                    name="cardmonth"
                    label="MM"
                    error={errors.cardmonth}
                    value={cardmonth}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    onBlur={validateInput}
                    helperText={errors.cardmonth && "Invalid month"}
                    className={classes.expiryDateInputs}
                  />
onChange=()=>{
  let cardMonth = /^0[1-9]|1[0-2]/.test(e.target.value);
        if (cardMonth === true) {
          setcardmonth(e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "").slice(0, 2));
          setErrors({ ...errors, cardmonth: false });
        } else {
          setErrors({ ...errors, cardmonth: true });
        }
        if (state.creditCard.cardyear !== "") {
          validateExpiryDate();
        }
```

}

passing states to non related components using below code:

```
const validateForm = () => {
    return actionsCollection.booking.validateForm(
      errors,
      setErrors,
      cardholder,
      setcardholder,
      cardnumber,
      setcardnumber,
      cardType,
      setCardType,
      cardmonth,
      setcardmonth,
      cardyear,
      setcardyear,
      cardcvv,
      setcardcvv,
      isCurrentCaseIncluded,
      cardYearValue
    );
  };
```

and in actions i am using this code:

```
const validateForm = (
    errors,
    setErrors,
    cardholder,
    setcardholder,
    cardnumber,
    setcardnumber,
    cardType,
    setCardType,
    cardmonth,
    setcardmonth,
    cardyear,
    setcardyear,
    cardcvv,
    setcardcvv,
    isCurrentCaseIncluded,
    cardYearValue
  ) => {
some validation logic.....
}
```

Problem is initial state is not updating, I am not getting what is wrong in my code, Anyone please help..

Comment: `onchange` in `TextField` should have a capitalized C: `onChange`

Comment: It's typo mistake, in my code it is capital only here it was typo mistake, now question is updated